# What does the grey color in some synonyms in Google define mean?

Tags: google-search, text-formatting

For example, here is the definition of *[zealous](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=define+zealous&sa=X&ei=VqfuVKv9IeX4mAXKvYIg&ved=0CDAQ_SowAA&biw=1366&bih=693)* I find when searching `define zealous`:

[image: image description]

Why are *hard-core*, *overkeen* and *literary* in grey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the definitions you get from Google actually the definitions of Oxford dictionary. So it's actually because Oxford dictionary doesn't give Google the link to those word:

[image: image description]

But I don't know why it doesn't link. Apparently those unlinked words exist in Oxford. And I don't know why Google can detect some words such as *devoted* or *vigorous* to link it, too.